# Постепенный вывод текста

Tags: c++, строки, текст

Хочу сделать постепенный вывод текста. У меня есть несколько текстов для постепенного вывода. Код:

```
int main()
{
    int time = 200;
    std::string a = "Gone";
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) 
    {
        Sleep(time);
        std::cout << a[i];
    }
    std::string b = "Dark";
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) 
    {
        Sleep(time);
        std::cout << b[i];
    }
}
```

Можно ли сделать одну переменную string для разных текстов, чтобы не создавать новые переменные постоянно?

Comment: Ну занесите весь текст в одну переменную и выводите его. Или присваивайте переменной типа `string` новое значение. Например `string a = "Gone"; a = "Dark"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно, можно.

```
std::string a;

a = "Gone";
for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) 
{
    Sleep(time);
    std::cout << a[i];
}
a = "Dark";
for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) 
{
    Sleep(time);
    std::cout << a[i];
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь